# Imageresizer and PrettyGifs plugin in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, imageresizer

How to use Imageresizer and PrettyGifs plugin for change png images to 16 colors.
This code not working, because PrettyGifs plugin must be set:
    `ImageBuilder.Current.Build("source.png", "destination.png", New ResizeSettings("format=png&colors=16"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find it:
 `Dim conf As New ImageResizer.Configuration.Config()`

```
Call (New PrettyGifs()).Install(conf)
conf.BuildImage("source.png", "destination.png", "format=png&colors=16")
```